# What is the use of confluent schema registry if Kafka can use Avro without it

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

The difference between vanilla apache Avro and Avro with confluent schema registry is that when using  apache avro , we send `schema+message` in kafka topic whereas in confluent schema registry , we send `schemaID+message` in kafka topic ? So here , schema registry helps in performance improvement via schema look up in registry. Is there any other benefit of using confluent schema registry ? Also , does apache avro supports compatabilty rules of schema evolution  like schema registry ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: There are *other* implementations of a "Schema Registry" that can use used with Kafka.

Here are a list of reasons

- Clients can discover schemas without interacting with Kafka. For example, Apache Hive / Presto / Spark can download schemas from the Registry to perform analytics.
- The registry is centrally responsible for compatibility checks rather than pushing each client to operate that on their own (to answer your second question)

The same applies to any serialization format, as well, not only Avro

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned Presto here — does Presto support Confluent Schema Registry in Kafka connector? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I recall finding a PR / github issue for it several years ago. But after the Trino rebranding, I'm not sure where that ended up. But if that doesn't exist, you'll need to add your own Kafka deserializer to the classpath of each Presto server

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are few more benefits. If proper ACL are not applied then any producer can send any message to kafka topic (may be by mistake) and using schema registry ensures that Producer can not send any random messages to topic and exception will be raised